# c2dm server block or not supported on lenovo tablets?

Tags: android, configuration, android-c2dm

I have been looking for c2dm servers for lenovo tablets because my boss has decided to use absolute manage for our android tablets. I was wondering if c2dm is supported on lenovo's thinkpad tablets? I have a similar question going on their forums but lenovo support takes forever to get back with you on an answer in their support forums.
Heres the white paper that will give more details so iam not off-topic too much:
http://www.absolute.com/shared/datasheets/am-mdm-ds-e.pdf
I will quote the line referring to google c2dm from page 2:
"Some android systems without access to google c2dm services may not be supported"

I need to get this done as fast as possible can anyone help me with this problem?

The actual problem is when absolute management application is opened I get it to communicate with absolutes mdm server which is contacted after the device sends a request to c2dm server. But in the process of getting it to communicate with the mdm server it gives me the error message: "Registration failed: connection error"

Somewhere googles c2dm server is not being contacted or dropped.

Comment: Sorry heres a direct address to the application for testing purposes: http://mdm.garrard.kyschools.us/AbsoluteApps.apk and the mdm server address should be the mdm to us part of the address with port 443

Comment: I gave the posters helpful posts because their information was sound. I found this to be weird because absolute support got an i-phone working before my eyes in a call with remote desktop and another support personal claims to have got the app below working on android. I trying to guess that it had to do with a firewall issue or the configuration is messed up for the absoluteapps.apk file. absolute support says it was supposed to not show me the port number and address when absoluteapps.apk installs and one support personnel got the apk file to work but I could not weird?

Comment: go to mdm.garrard.kyschools.us/Profile/enrollment.mdm on android and type this information: use username: mdmtest and password: test#1 and domain: garrard. This is the test username and password that will be disabled later after I get this working.

Comment: If anyone can reproduce the steps they did to get it working please share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are aware that C2DM has been deprecated and they are not accepting any new users? [as per their site](https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/?hl=de)

```
Important: C2DM has been officially deprecated as of June 26, 2012. This means that C2DM
has stopped accepting new users and quota requests. No new features will be added to C2DM. 
However, apps using C2DM will continue to work. Existing C2DM developers are encouraged to 
migrate to the new version of C2DM, called Google Cloud Messaging for Android (GCM). See the 
C2DM-to-GCM Migration document for more information. Developers must use GCM for new 
development.
```

Comment: Yes Iam aware of this. I found out this information long before I posted here. I do not know though if absolute has changed over to gcm yet or not.

Comment: @jeffery I am not sure what that means but if you don't already have a C2DM account with usage limits then I would not expect much luck.  What account are you using on C2DM?

Comment: will mark yours as answer because it appears someone else has had this problem for absolute mdm management software. Question: if they have too many customers then that will affect the quota and the extra users not be able to connect? However, if it appears to be a software problem I will have to talk with absolute mdm but thank you for your kind service.

Comment: You information might be useful as it turns out to be a certificate problem because the device will  not connect to the server when I  install a signed certificate onto the android device. In debug mode the android device will connect though. I am guessing the program is trying to use the old C2DM certificate or secure connection method in the background and its failing. Just trying to update this answer for usefulness

Answer (score 2):

Put this into your app and launch on Lenovo tablets

```
 // Make sure the device has the proper dependencies
GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(context);
// Make sure the manifest was properly set - comment out this line
// while developing the app, then uncomment it when it's ready.
GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(context);
```

And i think,if lenovo devices support google accounts they should support c2dm/gcm

Comment: Will try but doubt that will help solve anything. Does that check for proper communication with c2dm or the new gcm servers? (if it does forget what i said above in last sentence)